# Determining if current user is superuser with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, extjs

In Django, I can utilize template tags such as `{% if user.is_superuser %}` to determine if the current user is superuser. What is the recommended way to do it in a javascript file.

Thank you.

Comment: Typically you don't want to make those decisions on the front end as the user can alter most things on the front end. You would make a check every time they tried to do something, like submit a form, before you do anything check if they are a super user, if not return an error to display. What are you checking if they are a super user for?

Comment: @KevinF Thank you for the reply. I have a page I want to render buttons that are specific to general users, or buttons that are specific to admin users. Django template tags will allow me to do those checks in the html template, even under the `<script>` tag, without embedding it onto the markup because its all handled in the backend. My question was if I could do that, or something similar, in a javascript file instead of the html template. Because in order to keep my scripts organized, I wanted to keep the javascript in a separate js file and source it in the html template.

Answer (score 2):

Never do that in the front end code, anyone can modify that code and become a super user, you need to implement that at the back end when the user logs in the system and start a session that will be only for that particular super user and no can modify that from the front end

Comment: Okay, so how do you do it using Javascript? His question is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use any information in javascript from backend. there are various ways by which you can do that.

define a filter tag

here to_json is filter_tag you can define where you define tags or filters. In my case it is 'libs/commons/templatetags/common_filters.py'

```
@register.filter
def to_json(obj):
    return mark_safe(json.dumps(obj))
```

1- javascript variables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var someData = {% contextvariable|to_json %};
</script>
```

2- making meta tags in head

```
<meta id="dome_data_id" content="{% context_variable|to_json %}">
```

than accessing in javascript as follows
var some_data = JSON.parse($('#dome_data_id').attr('content'));

3 - making use of data attribute

```
<html_tag id="some_data_id" data-some_data="{% context_variable|to_json %}"></html_tag>
```

than accessing in javascript as follows

```
var some_data = JSON.parse($('#some_data_id').data('some_data'));
```

To check if user is super user you can use any of the above method. But if some form is submitted or request is sent by that user, it must be verified at backend, that user is actually a super user not some body else.

you can very well do it by if condition at backend

```
if request.user.is_superuser
# blah blah
```